# How can I import OS in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm running VS Code Version 1.5.3 with TypeScript 2 and I can't get my 'os' import to work. I managed to resolve other dependencies, such as Express, by running

```
typings install express --save
```

But I can't find a typing for OS. Probably since it's not a third party library. But then how do I resolve the following import?

`import { os } from 'os';`

The message I get in VS Code is *"Cannot find module 'os'"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a typings file. 
Ususally, you install typing files (ending in `d.ts`) from `typings`, which you install using `npm install -g typings` in the command line.

However, I can't seem to find a typing for `os` which is weird, so you can create a fake module definition to solve it in the meantime:

```
// file: os.d.ts
declare namespace os {
   interface OsStatic { ... everything os has ... }
}

declare var os: os.OsStatic;

declare module "os" {
    export = os;
}
```

What we do here can be separated into three parts:

1. the `namespace` defines the interfaces that compose the library
2. the `var` is the exported / main object of the library
3. the `module` is an ambient module, since it's name is a string. Using that string, visual studio can locate the module and allow you to import

In general, you should read about `typings` to manage typing files, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for me:

```
import * as os from 'os';
```